# how to lock on internalframe in java GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jinternalframe

im building a system with one JFrame and many JInternalFrames.
when i'm clicking on a button and JInternalFrame comes up i want to force the user to only be eable to click on that internalframe(the outside frame should be disabled), and just when he close the internalframe he can use the outside frame.

how do i do it?
thanks

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556044/how-to-lock-jinternal-frame-inside-jdesktoppane

Comment: it's not what i ment. here is an example.. http://imgur.com/aqm6KyO the left one is unclicked and the right one is clicked. i want that the user will se only the right one (with the frame) and will only click inside of the internal frame or the menu bar of the outside frame

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set an the modal attribute of the InternalFrame as true or to use an option pane: 
[JInternalFrame As Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422939/jinternalframe-as-modal)

Answer (score 0):

[How I can selected by default an InternalFrame on a JDesktopPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088223/how-i-can-selected-by-default-an-internalframe-on-a-jdesktoppane)

i found a good answer in this link at the bottom.
tnx everyone :)